# Not able to complete the word count program in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing some basic programs in scala

I am trying to get the word count program in scala

```
scala> val myWords = "HI HOW HI HOW ARE"
myWords: String = HI HOW HI HOW ARE

scala> val mySplit = myWords.split(" ")
mySplit: Array[String] = Array(HI, HOW, HI, HOW, ARE)

scala> val myMap = mySplit.map(x => (x,1))
 myMap: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((HI,1), (HOW,1), (HI,1), (HOW,1), (ARE,1))

 scala> val myCount = myMap.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)
 <console>:16: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of Array[(String, Int)]
   val myCount = myMap.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)
```

I am not sure what does this error mean?

So I tried to find what are the methods that I can invoke with

```
scala> val myCount = myMap.
apply          asInstanceOf   clone          isInstanceOf   length            toString       update
```

Could someone explains me where I went wrong in my code.

Comment: Does this have to be done with Spark? There are other vanilla ways to do this in Scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your code comes from an Apache Spark example. To do wordcount in plain Scala, you can use `groupBy` or `fold*` from the `Seq` trait.

**Edit:**
I see from your comment that you are indeed using spark. Then what you need to do is to turn your array into an `RDD` which has `reduceByKey`. So you use `sc.paralellize` to turn a `Seq` to an `RDD`. Then your code will work.

Comment: yes . I am trying this program from spark-shell  , So reduceByKey is not available if we give inputs on the fly ?

Comment: @SurenderRaja I updated my answer with info on what to do to get this to work in Spark

Answer (score 3):

A more "classy" solution to count words:

```
val myWords = "HI HOW HI HOW ARE"
val mySplit = myWords.split(" ")
.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
     (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
 }
```

And to answer what is wrong with your code : you are using the `reduceByKey`method which does not exist for the collection you are using.

Comment: So Can't we use reduceByKey in plain scala. If I want to use reduceByKey in plain scala then what is the collection do I need to invoke?

Comment: I cannot think of a collection which implements the `reduceByKey `method directly in plain Scala but by chaining method of the `Seq` trait, you can easily reproduce its behavior. As Simon said, try doing it with `fold` and `groupBy`.