# How to find keys within a text file and compare them to another using Spark & JSON

Tags: java, scala, file, dictionary, apache-spark

I'm currently learning Spark and I came across a problem that says give two text file find the books with a text review of more than 100 words and filter the results to only show the category of horror.

Here is an example of my two text files.
**BookInformation.data:**

Within this data file I have 4 Keys.

```
userName, price, categories, title
```

Each key has a value and each key is separated by a `,` as the delimiter. Some keys use a String Value while others use an Integer Value.

```
{"username": "JAMES250", "price": 19.20, "categories": "Horror", "title": "Friday the 13th"}
{"username": "Bro2KXA1", "price": 09.21, "categories": "Fantasy", "title": "Wizard of Oz"}
{"username": "LucyLu1272", "price": 18.69, "categories": "Fiction", "title": "Not Real"}
{"username": "6302049040", "price": 08.86, "categories": "Fantasy", "title": "Fantastic"} 
...
etc
...
```

**ReviewerText.data**

Within this data file I have 5 Keys.

```
reviewerID, userName, reviewText, overall, reviewTime
```

Each key has a value and each key is separated by a `,` as the delimiter. Some keys use a String Value while others use an Integer Value.

```
{"reviewerID": "A1R3P8MRFSN4X3", "username": "JAMES250", "reviewText": "Wow what a book blah blah… END", "overall": 4.0, "reviewTime": "08 9, 1997"}
{"reviewerID": "AVM91SKZ9M58T", " username ": " Bro2KXA1 ", "reviewText": "Different Blah Blah Blah Blah… So on… END", "overall": 5.0, "reviewTime": "08 10, 1997"}
{"reviewerID": "A1HC72VDRLANIW", " username ": "DiffUser09", "reviewText": "Another Review Blah Blah Blah Blah… So on… END", "overall": 1.0, "reviewTime": "08 19, 1997"}
{"reviewerID": "A2XBTS97FERY2Q", " username ": "MyNameIs01", "reviewText": "I love books. END", "overall": 5.0, "reviewTime": "08 23, 1997"}
...
etc
...
```

My Goal here is simple.

1. First I want to check **ReviewInformation.data** for any `reviewText` more than 100 words.
2. Once I have found every `reviewText` with more than 100 words I want to sort the results in order of `overall` rating; starting from 5 to 1. Then I need to also print the corresponding `Title` to each one as well.
3. After that I need to restart the filter and I only need to filter out the `categories` from **BookInformation.data** to show only the `Horror` category.
4. Then calculate the average number of words that appear within the `reviewText` for the `Horror` category.

**Code:**
So far what I have is that I am creating a Key:Value array for each line entry in each file. The goal here is to create an Array I can parse for any Key and receive its Value.

```
package main.scala

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine
import scala.io.Source

object ReviewDataSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //Create a SparkContext to initialize Spark
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local")
    conf.setAppName("Word Count")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val metaDataFile = sc.textFile("/src/main/resources/BookInformation.data")
    val reviewDataFile = sc.textFile("/src/main/resources/ReviewText.data")

    reviewDataFile.flatMap { line => {
      val Array(label, rest) = line split ","
      println(Array)
      val items = rest.trim.split("\\s+")
      println(items)
      items.map(item => (label.trim -> item))
     } 
    }

    metaDataFile.flatMap { line => {
      val Array(label, rest) = line split ","
      println(Array)
      val items = rest.trim.split("\\s+")
      println(items)
      items.map(item => (label.trim -> item))
     }
    }

  }
}
```

**Issues:**
So my main issue with the code is that I do not believe I am using flatMap correctly. I can't seem to spilt the Keys and Values into a Array of Keys.

My code just prints out:
`Process finished with exit code 0`

It doesn't seem correct.

**EDIT:**

So i updated my code to use JSON library.

```
val jsonColName = "json"
// intermediate column name where we place each line of source data
val jsonCol = col(jsonColName) // its reusable ref
val metaDataSet = spark.read.textFile("src/main/resources/BookInformation.data")
  .toDF(jsonColName).select(get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.username")
  .alias("username"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.price")
  .alias("price"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.categories")
  .alias("categories"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.title")
  .alias("title"))

val reviewDataSet = spark.read.textFile("src/main/resources/reviewText.data")
  .toDF(jsonColName).select(get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.reviewerID")
  .alias("reviewerID"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.username")
  .alias("username"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.reviewText")
  .alias("reviewText"), get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.overall")
  .alias("overall").as[Double], get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.reviewTime")
  .alias("reviewTime"))
reviewDataSet.show()
metaDataSet.show()
```

Then I was able to merge thanks to the information.

```
val joinedDataSets = metaDataSet.join(reviewDataSet, Seq("username"))
    joinedDataSets.show()
```

Now my next step is to be able to count the number of words inside `joinedDataSets` in the column `ReviewText` and only keep those that are above 100 words.

How can I filter the JSON object from the key `reviewText` and then count all the entries and remove the ones with less than 100 Words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to load the data from the files in a structured manner. Each line of the source files can be parsed as JSON and the information should be placed properly in the respective columns.

For example, to load and parse `BookInformation.data`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ // necessary for col, get_json_object functions and others below

val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("My app")
                         .master("local[*]")
                         .getOrCreate()

val bookInfoFilePath = // path to BookInformation.data

val jsonColName = "json" // intermediate column name where we place each line of source data
val jsonCol = col(jsonColName) // its reusable ref

val bookInfoDf = session.read.textFile(bookInfoFilePath).toDF(jsonColName).select(
  get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.username").alias("username"),
  get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.price").alias("price"),
  get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.categories").alias("categories"),
  get_json_object(jsonCol, "$.title").alias("title")
)
```

So now we have a book information DataFrame containing properly structured data:

```
bookInfoDf.show()
+----------+-----+----------+---------------+
|  username|price|categories|          title|
+----------+-----+----------+---------------+
|  JAMES250| 19.2|    Horror|Friday the 13th|
|  Bro2KXA1| 9.21|   Fantasy|   Wizard of Oz|
|LucyLu1272|18.69|   Fiction|       Not Real|
|6302049040| 8.86|   Fantasy|      Fantastic|
+----------+-----+----------+---------------+
```

The answers to Q3 and Q4 become quite obvious to obtain.

```
val dfQuestion3 = bookInfoDf.where($"categories" === "Horror")
dfQuestion3.show()
+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
|username|price|categories|          title|
+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
|JAMES250| 19.2|    Horror|Friday the 13th|
+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
```

For Q4, you'll have to join `bookInfoDf` with the DataFrame loaded from `ReviewerText.data`, using `username` column, then aggregate (`.agg`) the data on average length of `reviewText` column (`avg` and `length` functions).

To load `ReviewerText.data`, you can proceed exactly by analogy with how `bookInfoDf` was loaded above. `overall` column should be converted to numeric using `.as[Double]` after `.alias` call.

*Update*

> I had a question about how to count the number of words within a JSON Key/Value. For example, in the key reviewText I have create and merged both BookInformation and ReviewText into one dataset. Now If i wanted to loop through each reviewText and count the number of words then filter either keep or remove depending on the amount of words within the Key's Value how would I go about doing that? I'm trying to learn how to extract value

One of possible ways to do it is by caculating the number of words and storing it in a dedicated column:

```
// reviewerTextDf is the DataFrame with original data from ReviewerText.data
val dfWithReviewWordsCount = reviewerTextDf.withColumn("nb_words_review", size(split($"reviewText", "\\s+")))

dfWithReviewWordsCount.show()
```

Which gives the folowing:

```
+--------------+--------+--------------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|    reviewerID|username|          reviewText|overall| reviewTime|nb_words_review|
+--------------+--------+--------------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|A1R3P8MRFSN4X3|JAMES250|Wow what a book b...|    4.0| 08 9, 1997|              7|
| AVM91SKZ9M58T|    null|Different Blah Bl...|    5.0|08 10, 1997|              8|
|A1HC72VDRLANIW|    null|Another Review Bl...|    1.0|08 19, 1997|              9|
|A2XBTS97FERY2Q|    null|   I love books. END|    5.0|08 23, 1997|              4|
+--------------+--------+--------------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: I have editted my Post to show my JSON code. I had a question about how to count the number of words within a JSON Key/Value. For example, in the key `reviewText` I have create and merged both BookInformation and ReviewText into one dataset. Now If i wanted to loop through each `reviewText` and count the number of words then filter either keep or remove depending on the amount of words within the Key's Value how would I go about doing that? I'm trying to learn how to extract value

Comment: I updated my answer with one of possible approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I create a filter after making the WordCount Column and worked perfectly! `val reviewTextWordCount = joinedDataSets.withColumn("numberOfWords", size(split($"reviewText", "\\s")))
    reviewTextWordCount.filter($"numberOfWords" > 100).show()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create two dataframes and load the data from files into two dfs:

1.One with books

```
(val books_df = spark.read.json("/some/path/.json"))
```

2.One with reviewers

```
(val reviewers_df = spark.read.json("/some/path/.json"))
```

Join the dfs as tables based on book.username == reviewer.username to get a third JOINED_DF.

```
 (val joined_df = books_df.join(reviewers_df, Seq("usernamer"), type_of_join))
```

Now you can filter the df as per categories and get the word count too.
For using the flat-map correctly for word count, i would suggest you to refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37680132/4482149.

Comment: It seems my spark does not have the library for json. `spark.read.json()` does not work. What imports do i need for json?

Comment: @JeanP As per my understanding, You should not need a library to read the json as a dataframe. Try this : 

`import spark.implicits._`  

`val some_df = sqlContext.read.schema(some_schema).json("path of json file")`